# Update with modal file upload form

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, file-upload, bootstrap-modal

So, I have a modal form. For the insert function, use the regular form and it works.
but in the update function with the modal form, the scheme runs and an alert indicating the update was successful appears, but no changes occur.

This is the modal call with a button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editsop{{$data->id_sop}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

and this is my modal form

```
    @foreach ($sop as $data)
<div class="modal fade" id="editsop{{$data->id_sop}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg-6">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editsopModal">Update SOP</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="/sop/update/{id_sop}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input name="sop" type="text" class="form-control @error('sop') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $data->sop }}">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @error('sop')
                    {{ $message }}
                    @enderror
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="div-col-sm-6">
                        <img src="{{ url('foto_sop/'.$data->file_sop) }}" width="100px">
                    </div>
                    <input name="file_sop" type="file" class="form-control @error('file_sop') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $data->file_sop }}">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        @error('file_sop')
                        {{ $message }}
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

my update controller

```
public function update($id_sop)
{
    Request()->validate(
        [
            'file_sop' => 'mimes:pdf,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000'
        ],
        [
            'file_sop.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
            'file_sop.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB'
        ]
    );

    //jika ingin ganti berkas 
    if (Request()->file_sop <> "") {
        //upload gambar/foto
        $file = Request()->file_sop;
        $fileName = Request()->sop . '.' . $file->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan nama file_sop
        $file->move(public_path('file_sop'), $fileName);

        $data = [
            'sop' => Request()->sop,
            'file_sop' => $fileName,
            'created_at' => Request()->created_at,
            'updated_at' => Request()->updated_at
        ];

        $this->SopModel->editData($id_sop, $data);
    } else {
        $data = [
            'sop' => Request()->sop,
            'created_at' => Request()->created_at,
            'updated_at' => Request()->updated_at
        ];
    
        $this->SopModel->editData($id_sop, $data);
    }
    return redirect()->route('sop')->with('pesan', 'Data Berhasil Di Update !!!');
}
```

and this is my update modal

```
public function editData($id_sop, $data)
{
    DB::table('sop')
        ->where('id_sop', $id_sop)
        ->update($data);
}
```

and finally this is the route update

```
Route::post('/sop/update/{id_sop}', [App\Http\Controllers\SOPController::class, 'update']);
```

So, where do I think my mistake was, I've been trying to find out all night, but still haven't found the point of the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not correctly passing the `id_sop` to your update function. In your form action, you're using a placeholder `{id_sop}`, but you're not replacing it with the actual `id_sop` value.

```html
<form action="/sop/update/{{$data->id_sop}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This way, the `id_sop` will be correctly passed to your update function in the controller.

Also, in your update function, you're using `Request()` to get the request data. However, you should use the `request` parameter in the function definition to get the request data. Here's how you should define your update function:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id_sop)
```

Then, you can use `$request` instead of `Request()` to get the request data:

```php
if ($request->file_sop <> "") {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: great, it works..
I just found out now that writing code like I wrote before is no longer possible, even though 1 year ago I did the same thing and it was possible.
Thank you Jazakallah Khairan for your help, I hope all your affairs will be easy

Comment: oh yes that's right, it turns out I made a mistake in writing {}, it should be {{ }} hahaha

Comment: and also the wrong calling, oh poor me